# How to initialise the function only on Button click and not on reloading/refresh?

Tags: angularjs

This is my main.html where I use Angular JS with my API using CodeIgniter and other to check if the Payment status `userhold.is_hold_payment` is 0, display **Hold**, and if 1, display **Unhold**.

This works perfectly fine, as it gets updated in the database as well but when I refresh the page, the function is initialised. I only want it when I click on the button. but it gets changed when I refresh. what do I do? Here is the main.html

```
<div  ng-init="userhold_payment()">
<button type="button" ng-click="userhold_payment();" ng-if="userhold.is_hold_payment == 0" class="btn-success btn-lg hold_payment_html" style="margin-top:7px; font-size:16px">Hold Payment</button>
<button type="button" ng-click="userhold_payment();" ng-if="userhold.is_hold_payment == 1" class="btn-danger btn-lg hold_payment_html" style="margin-top:7px; font-size:16px">Unhold Payment</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Please post code of userhold_payment() as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove

```
ng-init="userhold_payment()"
```

this cause the function to fire when you refresh

to fix your code use this:

```
<div>
<button type="button" ng-click="userhold_payment();" ng-class="btn-success btn-lg hold_payment_html" style="margin-top:7px; font-size:16px">Refresh userhold</button>

<button type="button" ng-click="userhold_payment();" ng-if="userhold && userhold.is_hold_payment && userhold.is_hold_payment == 0" class="btn-success btn-lg hold_payment_html" style="margin-top:7px; font-size:16px">Hold Payment</button>
<button type="button" ng-click="userhold_payment();" ng-if="userhold && userhold.is_hold_payment && userhold.is_hold_payment == 1" class="btn-danger btn-lg hold_payment_html" style="margin-top:7px; font-size:16px">Unhold Payment</button>
</div>
```

Comment: You are right, but my ng-if="userhold.is_hold_payment == 0" won't work without it. I am using MVC (Code Igniter) and I call from the controller. Where userhold is the name and .is_hold_payment the key.

Answer (score 0):

As Arno stated [and the docs describe](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit) ngInit evaluates (runs) the function on the page load, and you should remove it.

Comment: You are right, but my ng-if="userhold.is_h‌​old_payment == 0" won't work without it. I am using MVC (Code Igniter) and I call from the controller. Where userhold is the name and .is_hold_payment the key.